# First nodejs app - Why is the 'Pool' undefined even if I require('pg').Pool

Tags: node.js

I am writing my first nodejs app and having some problems. 
The error is : ReferenceError: Pool is not defined

index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const Client = require('pg').Pool 


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("Wassup!");
});


const client = new Pool({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: the problem is here : `client = new Pool(..)` either store `pg.Pool` as `Pool` instead of `Client` or use `client = new Client(..)` instead

Comment: You imported `Pool` but said its variable name is `Client` so you have to use that `Client` name in your code. Calling `client = new Client({...})` should work

Comment: Why you didn't import directly const { Pool } = require('pg') like the documentation https://node-postgres.com/api/pool

Comment: I just did it, thank you all. But the client.query is not working, does any1 know why? It doesn't select anything

Comment: the query returns an error or no rows? If no rows try to create some table first, then run it again

Comment: no errors, but no rows. I've created table in pgAdmin, its connected to heroku, and to github. When i push the database to heroku it says the database is not empty, so I am assuming that the fact that the app on heroku is connected to Postgres(where my db is) so all the data is already there right?

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with so little background information and a complex workflow. Try communicating with heroku staff, or else post a new question with ALL relevant information included (else it will possibly be closed)